# MYSQL Trigger Query

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am attempting to create a trigger to update quantities between 2 separate databases. This query runs successfully, but when I show triggers in mysql, it brings up an empty set. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
delimiter $$ CREATE TRIGGER `quantity_to_clb` AFTER UPDATE ON product 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN UPDATE cl_boutique.product AS clb 
LEFT JOIN cherrylane.product AS cl 
ON clb.model = cl.code SET clb.quantity = cl.available
 WHERE clb.model = cl.code
 END $$ 
delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your code has two synax errors:

```
delimiter $$ --delimiter statements need to be on separate lines
CREATE TRIGGER `quantity_to_clb` AFTER UPDATE ON product 
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
  UPDATE cl_boutique.product AS clb 
  LEFT JOIN cherrylane.product AS cl 
  ON clb.model = cl.code SET clb.quantity = cl.available
   WHERE clb.model = cl.code; -- ; was needed here
END $$ 
delimiter ;
```